# Why do I get the error " NameError: uninitialized constant Gmails::Username"

Tags: ruby, rspec

How can I pass the value of row[0,1] in Gmails.SetPassword.Please suggest change for the same.Below is the code for the same.

```
module Gmails
  extend RSpec::Matchers
  extend Capybara::DSL

  $Gmails_Username_Input= "//input[@id='identifierId']"
  $Gmails_IdentifierNext_Button="div[id= 'identifierNext']"
  $Gmails_Password_Input="input[name= 'password']"
  $Gmails_PasswordNext_Button="div[id='passwordNext']"

  book = Spreadsheet.open('Data.xls')
  sheet1 = book.worksheet('Sheet1') # can use an index or worksheet name
  sheet1.each do |row|
    break if row[0].nil? # if first cell empty
    puts row.join(',') # looks like it calls "to_s" on each cell's Value
    puts row[0,1]
  end

  def Gmails.OpenGmail
    visit "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin"
  end  

  def Gmails.SetEmailId
    Gmails.SetElement $Gmails_Username_Input, row[0,1]
  end

  def Gmails.ClickNext
    Gmails.ClickElement $Gmails_IdentifierNext_Button
  end

  def Gmails.SetPassword
    Gmails.SetElement $Gmails_Password_Input, row[1,1]
  end

  def Gmails.ClickPasswordNext
    Gmails.ClickElement $Gmails_PasswordNext_Button
  end

  def Gmails.ClickElement objectpath
    if(objectpath.start_with?('/'))
      find(:xpath, objectpath).click
    else
      find(:css, objectpath).click
    end
  end

  def Gmails.SetElement objectpath ,gmailsTextValue
    if(objectpath.start_with?('/'))
      find(:xpath, objectpath).set gmailsTextValue
    else
      find(:css, objectpath).set gmailsTextValue
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ruby is not Javascript...

Comment: @ManishaSingh: I don't think you get this error message **for the code you have posted**, because there is no reference to a module `Gmails::Username`. Which line number does the error message refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I can't make any sense of it before refactoring your code to look like Ruby:

```
module Gmails
  extend RSpec::Matchers
  extend Capybara::DSL

  book = Spreadsheet.open('Data.xls')
  sheet1 = book.worksheet('Sheet1') # can use an index or worksheet name
  sheet1.each do |row|
    break if row[0].nil? # if first cell empty
    puts row.join(',') # looks like it calls "to_s" on each cell's Value
    puts row[0,1]
  end

  def open_gmail
    visit "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin"
  end

  def set_email_id(id)
    set_element "//input[@id='identifierId']", id
  end

  def click_next
    click_element "div[id= 'identifierNext']"
  end

  def set_password(password)
    set_element "input[name= 'password']", password
  end

  def click_password_next
    click_element "div[id='passwordNext']"
  end

  def find_element(object_path)
    find(object_path.start_with?('/') ? :xpath : :css, object_path)
  end

  def click_element(object_path)
    find_element(object_path).click
  end

  def set_element(object_path, value)
    find_element(object_path).set(value)
  end
end
```

Ok, easier for the eyes now. Also notice, how I added the `id` and `password` parameters into the `set_email_id` and `set_password` methods. Now you can call them like `set_password("secret_password")`.

I think, when you're asking "how to pass `row[0,1]`" you actually do not want to do that. I believe `row[0]` is the contents of the first column, so:

```
row = ['hello', 'world']
row[0] # => 'hello'
```

When you call `row[0,1]` you're not asking for the value of the first column, you're asking for a slice of the array:

```
row[0,1] # => ['hello']
# same as: 
row.slice(0,1) # => ['hello']
```

What I believe you actually want is, is to pass the value of the first column into the `set_password` method:

```
def set_password(password)
  set_element "input[name= 'password']", password
end

set_password(row[0])
```